# How to disable Django signals in View?

Tags: django, django-signals

I'm writing a migration script and I don't want the signals to be triggered.
How do I disconnect signal from views?

**View.py**

```
pre_save.disconnect( pre_save_callback, sender=MyModel)
```

**Error:**

```
NameError: name 'pre_save_callback' is not defined
```

**signal handler:**

```
@receiver(pre_save,sender=MyModel)
def pre_save_callback(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    '''
    do some stuff
    '''
    print('running pre_save')
```

---

**Fixed! Updated view code**

The missing part was importing the signal handler function to the view and use it as the parameter in pre_save.disconnect().

At first, I thought that it will do an automatic look up of the function just by passing the function name as string. Hope this helps someone.

**View.py**

```
from app.signals.handler import pre_save_callback
pre_save.disconnect( pre_save_callback, sender=MyModel)
```

Comment: As the error shows, you are not using a valid function name.

Comment: sorry, i don't get it.  `pre_save_callback` is defined in the signal handler, not in view.py. does this mean that i need to import the function to the view?

Comment: I've update my question, please check the signal handler.

Comment: Still the question is not complete. But i get the feeling that you have forgotten the import

Comment: i just imported my function from the signals. it's working now!  Thanks @e4c5

Comment: glad to have been of help